# How to solve MemoryError on calling pickle.load()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm a beginner for deep-learning world. That's why I'm testing sample code for classifying image.

However, I got error message like as MemoryError soon after executing train.py.

This sample code is from below URL.

https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-3-deep-learning-and-convolutional-neural-networks-f40359318721

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~/work/tflearn$ ll
total 5794836
drwxr-xr-x 3 steven steven       4096  3월  9 15:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 steven steven       4096  2월 27 17:16 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 steven steven      12288  2월 28 11:56 .full_dataset.pkl.swp
-rw-r--r-- 1 steven steven        147  2월 27 17:20 checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 steven steven      61214  2월 27 17:52 convnet_cifar10.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steven steven  450189480  2월 28 10:32 data.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steven steven 5483602303  6월 13  2016 full_dataset.pkl
drwxr-xr-x 2 steven steven       4096  2월 27 17:19 mnist/
-rw-r--r-- 1 steven steven       2884  2월 27 17:47 train.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 steven steven       2611  2월 28 11:50 train2.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 steven steven       2483  2월 27 17:19 weights_persistence.py
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~/work/tflearn$ 
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~/work/tflearn$ python train.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 20, in <module>
    X, Y, X_test, Y_test = pickle.load(open("full_dataset.pkl", "rb"))
MemoryError
```

My pc's specification is as below.

- OS : Ubuntu 64bit
- CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
- Memory : 11350MB

Comment: Memory error with 11.3 Gigs?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have enough RAM to open the file, pickle is known for requiring a 2-3 times more RAM than the size of the data.

Comment: Okay, let me minimize dataset size as under 3GB and make a test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it would help but try:

Instead of this:

```
X, Y, X_test, Y_test = pickle.load(open("full_dataset.pkl", "rb"))
```

Try:

```
with open("full_dataset.pkl", "rb") as file_object:
    X, Y, X_test, Y_test = pickle.load(file_object)
#Do further Stuff
```

Comment: I got same result after applying new code that you recommend. : (  Thanks anyway.